# Update quantity on a cart issue

Tags: php

I have a built a php based shopping cart. Everything works except this last part. When you click on the update quantity, it updates every item in the carts quantity. And I cant quite figure out why. Here is the code for the button:

***EDIT***

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();

// connect to database
//include 'config/db_connect.php';
include 'config/sa_db_connect.php';

// set page title
$page_title="Shopping Cart";

// include page header html
include 'layout_head.php';



$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']) : "";

if($action=='removed') {
echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> was removed from your cart!";
echo "</div>";


}else if($action=='quantity_updated'){
echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
    echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> quantity was updated!";
echo "</div>";
}

if(count($_SESSION['cart'])>0){

// remove all cart contents
echo "<div class='right-button-margin' style='overflow:hidden;'>";
    echo "<a href='empty_cart.php' class='btn btn-default pull-right'>Empty Cart</a>";
echo "</div>";





// get the product ids
$ids = "";
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id=>$value){
    $ids = $ids . $id . ",";
}

// remove the last comma
$ids = rtrim($ids, ',');

//start table
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered' style='margin:1em 0 0 0;'>";

    // our table heading
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Price (GBP)</th>";
        echo "<th style='width:15em;'>Quantity</th>";
        echo "<th>Sub Total</th>";
        echo "<th>Action</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $query = "SELECT idsale_Stock, model_no, sale_price FROM sale_Stock WHERE idsale_Stock IN ({$ids}) ORDER BY cat_description";
    // $query = "SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id IN ({$ids}) ORDER BY name";

    $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();

    $total_price=0;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);

        $quantity=$_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'];
        $sub_total=$sale_price*$quantity;

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo "<div class='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>";
                echo "<div class='product-name'>{$model_no}</div>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>&#163;" . number_format($sale_price, 2, '.', ',') . "</td>";
            echo "<td>";

            echo "<form class='update-quantity-form'>";
            echo "<div class='input-group'>";
            echo "<input type='number' name='quantity' value='{$quantity}' min='1' class='form-control' required>";
            echo "<span class='input-group-btn'>";
            echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default update-quantity'>Update</button>";
            echo "</span>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</form>";
```

Comment: This doesn't tell us much... All it's showing us in the quantity, but perhaps the issues lies in the fact that you seem to lack a ID for the actual product that should be updated.

Comment: your page is reloading and updating while clicking on the update quantity right?

Comment: Correct. The page reloads on click.

Comment: A bit of code would be _how can I put this_ **kinda useful**

Comment: Epodax, how could i implement the ID in there?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Aaarrrgggg **extract($row);** No No No.

Comment: There is **no code in there** that amends the quantities of anything in the cart!!!

Comment: OK. I figured that out, but thank you. My question is how could i do that?

Comment: QUOTE: _I have a built a php based shopping cart. Everything works except this last part_ which I find dificult to believe judging by the code I see and the question asked. So write some code for this last part. SO is **not a free coding service**

Answer (score -2):

in update-quantity the button type is submit. so when clicking the button, the page is reloading.

remove type="submit" from update-quantity. and try.

if you want any action when clicking the button, you can use onclick.

or please use event.preventdefault() to avoid the form submission.

thanks.

Comment: And what is going to happen when the page does not submit? I would say **absolutely nothing is going to happen**

Comment: event.preventdefault()

Comment: Can you see any reference to **javascript** in this question?

Comment: you cant fix this issue with type="submit"

Comment: if you find any way then let me know.